# Android - Change text colour of the bottom button bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-button, android-styles

I'm modifying downloads (for 4.3 Jellybean) and I can't change the colour of the text on the bottom button from black to white. Is it possible to change the text colour without giving the button its own style by adding an item in the app theme? Here is my Styles.xml:

```
<style name="DownloadListTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DialogWhenLarge">
   <item name="android:textAlignment">viewStart</item>
   <item name="android:layoutDirection">locale</item>
   <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse</item>
   <item name="com.sonyericsson.uxp:extendedLookAndFeel">true</item>
   <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can accomplish this pretty easily, just override your theme in styles.xml like this:

```
<style name="MyButtonStyle"
   parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Light.DialogWhenLarge">
   <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

For more information, see the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

Comment: that's not exactly what I want, is it possible do it without creating an individual style for the button and have all style items under the app theme?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you edit your question to post a screenshot of what you want to change? Also, what is my solution doing that is different from what you want?

Comment: Your solution worked on making the text change colour, (I don't think I said exactly what I wanted though). What I want to do change the text colour without adding extra styles and just add an item, the reason I think this is possible is when the theme is changed the button text changes colour so I concluded there might be an item which does this.

Comment: If you can obtain a reference to the actual button (by using findViewById() somehow) that you want to change, you can call `button.setTextColor(...)` on that button itself, without changing anything else.  @Longatom